# Group rows in text file and aggregate corresponding rows to column

Tags: bash, awk

Group rows in text file and aggregate corresponding rows to column

**Existing text file**

```
John|Life
John|Temp
John|Admin
Peter|Life
Peter|Admin
Matt|Life
Matt|Admin
Matt|Temp
```

**Desired output**

```
John|Life,Temp,Admin
Peter|Life,Admin
Matt|Life,Temp,Admin
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### command

```
awk -F '|' '
$1==x{
    printf ",%s", $2
    next
}
{
    x=$1
    printf "\n%s|%s", $1, $2
}
END {
    printf "\n"
}' input.txt
```

---

#### result

```
John|Life,Temp,Admin
Peter|Life,Admin
Matt|Life,Admin,Temp
```

Comment: I use `x` to store 1st field of current record.

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` solution:

```
sed -e ':a;$!{N;ba};:p' \
 -e 's/^\([^|\n]*|\)\([^\n]*\)\(.*\n\)\1\([^|\n]*\)/\1\2,\4\3/' \
 -e 'tp;s/\n*\n/\n/;P;D;bp' filename
```